# Is it possible to use pattern matching in the map function in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, pattern-matching

For example I have an array:

```
let a = [1, "a", 2.0]
```

can I use pattern matching in the map function to apply for example a multiplication only on integers?

in scala it would look something like this:

```
a map { b => b match {
    case n: Int => n * 2
    case _ => b
}}
```

Is this possible in swift?

Comment: Ideally it would actually be `a map { case n: Int => n * 2 case _ => b }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching in Swift can be done with the `switch` statement:

```
let a : [Any] = [1, "a", 2.0]
let r = map(a) {
    b -> Any in
    switch b {
    case let n as Int:
        return n * 2
    case let d as Double:
        return d / 2.0
    default:
        return b
    }
}
println(r)
// Output: [2, a, 1.0]
```